# Wordpress Custom Post Type - Categories Now Showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type for a site and I have categories showing on the post in the admin, but when I call them on the public site, the list is always blank. I am not sure what I am missing.

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
/* Custom Post Type Galleries */

function bhgallery_register_post_type() {

    $singular = 'Gallery';
    $plural = 'Galleries';

    $labels = array (
        'name' => $plural,
        'singular' => $singular,
        'add_name' => 'Create New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Create New ' . $singular,
        'edit' => 'Edit',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'new_item' => 'New' . $singular,
        'view' => 'View' . $singular,
        'view_item' => 'View' . $singular,
        'search_term' => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'parent' => 'Parent ' . $singular,
        'not_found' => 'No ' . $plural . ' Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No ' . $plural . ' in Trash'

    );

    $args = array ( 
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'public_queryable'      => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'menu_position'         => 10,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-camera',
        'can_export'            => true,
        'delete_with_user'      => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        // 'capabilities' => array();
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'slug'          => 'gallery',
            'with_front'    => true,
            'pages'         => true,
            'feeds'         => false,
        ),
        'supports'              => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor'
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'bh_gallery', $args );

}

add_action ( 'init', 'bhgallery_register_post_type');


/** Custom Categories for Gallery **/

function bhgallery_register_taxonomy() {

    $plural = 'Categories';
    $singular = 'Category';

    $labels = array (
            'name'                      => $plural,
            'singular_name'             => $singular,
            'search_items'              => 'Search ' . $plural,
            'popular_items'             => 'Popular ' . $plural,
            'all_items'                 => 'All ' . $plural,
            'parent_item'               => null,
            'parent_item_colon'         => null,
            'edit_item'                 => 'Edit ' . $singular,
            'update_item'               => 'Update ' . $singular,
            'add_new_item'              => 'Add New ' . $singular,
            'new_item_name'             => 'New ' . $singular . ' Name',
            'separate_items_with_comas' => 'Seperate ' . $singular . ' with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items'       => 'Add or remove ' . $plural,
            'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from the most used ' . $plural,
            'not_found'                 => 'No ' . $plural . 'fount',
            'menu_name'                 => $plural,
        );

    $args = array (
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'categories'),
        );

    register_taxonomy( 'gallery category', 'bh_gallery', $args );
}

add_action ( 'init', 'bhgallery_register_taxonomy');
```

HOME PAGE

```
<div class="portfolio-categories">Categories:<?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using to show the categories - are you using this within The Loop? If not, then it's only going to get categories for the current post (which, if it's the homepage, is probably none).

Otherwise if you are trying to get all terms for your post type, using get_terms() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms will allow you to get your terms by post type and then you could loop them to display them:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

=================== UPDATE ==============
Thanks for your clarification - try using the following instead to fetch your custom taxonomy in the loop:

```
<div class="portfolio-categories">Categories:<?php the_terms(get_the_ID(),'gallery_category'); ?></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have better clarified, yes it is within the loop. I have the title of each post showing just fine, featured image showing just fine, but for some reason the categories are not. I even put what you have (Outside the look) and it is blank. Could it be something with how I created the custom taxonomy in functions.php?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - try this instead:

<div class="portfolio-categories">Categories:<?php the_terms(get_the_ID(),'gallery category'); ?></div>

Comment: That works great.. not to bug you more, but I am also using the category in the class of the <li> that it belongs to, but that returns the whole link for the category... what if I just wanted to return the category name but no long? Thanks again!

Comment: PS your original function for out of a loop did work, I just had the wrong term, I put the custom post type instead of the custom taxonomy. OOPS!